# How to convert the DataGridView content into a List<> of custom objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, custom-object

I'm working on a Windows Forms application, written with C#.

I found someone's suggestion on how to create a `List<>` from `DataGridView` control, but I need little more help on how to extract cell values.

Here is the code given; let's say two columns in the `dataGridView1` are `Name` and `Address`.
How to build the `List<ProjList>` object?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    ProjList = new List<ProjectMasterRec>();

    foreach (DataGridViewCell dc in dr.Cells)
    {
        // build out MyItem
        // based on DataGridViewCell.OwningColumn and DataGridViewCell.Value
        // how do we code this?
    }

    ProjList.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: do you want to get all row column data and insert it in to list as one record in the form of string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try It this Way

Create a list of your class type

```
List<ProjectMasterRec>() ProjList = new List<ProjectMasterRec>();
```

Make Sure that type of list belongs to type of your data in Datagridview

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    //Create object of your list type pl
    ProjectMasterRec pl = new ProjectMasterRec();
    pl.Property1 = dr.Cells[1].Value;
    pl.Property2 = dr.Cells[2].Value;
    pl.Property3 = dr.Cells[3].Value;

    //Add pl to your List  
    ProjList.Add(pl);     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to use LINQ, you can do something like this:

```
var projectList = (from row in dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                   select new ProjectMasterRec() 
                   { Name = row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString(),
                     Address = row.Cells["Address"].Value.ToString() 
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: I am getting an error in the your Linq that dgvTest does not exists in current context.  How to I convert var projectList to List? When we are converting the query with .ToList() then why can't we assign directly to a List. I don't want to use var since I will be using list later.

Comment: @user2026794 - The variable `dgvTest` was for illustration. Use your actual variable `dataGridView1`, I have updated my answer too. `var` is an implicit local type, its not the same as `System.Object`, so in the above case, `var` becomes `List<ProjectMasterRec>`.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work, `myArray` should be an array of the type you need, you can find out the array size using `(DataGrid1.DataSource as BindingSource).List.Count`.

```
(DataGrid1.DataSource as BindingSource).List.CopyTo(myArray, 0);
```